# Positioning an image inside a link

Tags: html, css

I’ve got some markup that doesn’t have much flexibility. It contains a simple link with an image inside of it. I’m trying to use CSS to get the image to display below the text. However, the only way I can do this is with absolute positioning. I thought there was another way to do this without having to resort to that. Any ideas? Also, I’m trying to get the image to display to the right of the text. I can do this by floating the image to the right, but the image appears all the way to the right of the container. Does anyone know how I can get the image to appear right next to the text? I don't really have the flexibility of adding a span tag around the link text.

```css
a img{ position: absolute; top:30px }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150”> 
  Enter Header
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using `position` as you mentioned in your question, and keeping the same HTML you can put image right sided to text:

see the snippet below:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
a img {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />Enter Header
</a>
```

**UPDATE** Based on OP question in comment here is how to put text above image.

> *Thanks, what about the instance when I want the text above the image?*

**and after a discussion with OP, it was possible to use `position` after all.**

```css
a {
  position: relative;
}
a img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />Enter Header
</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however I don't have flexibility as far as moving the html around or adding a span tag around the text so this really wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood your question, let me redo my answer

Comment: Thanks, what about the instance when I want the text above the image?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me with the text above the image based on your last snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62543/discussion-between-dippas-and-delmon-young).

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS display block.

http://jsfiddle.net/nt44h5r5/15/

```
a img {

}
```

To use float properly, you need to have a container (DIV) at a set width.  I believe this is what you're looking for (jsfidd link).

Comment: Also..top:30px doesn't mean anything to the CSS.  If you want a margin top, use margin-top: 30px;  Play around with it in the code and see.

Comment: This doesn't answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Updated to address OP's questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the a as block, and relative:

```
a { display: block; position: relative }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
a img {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float:right;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:150px; (or any height of the image)
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Monteduro/nt44h5r5/14/

Comment: Thanks, what about the instance when I want the text above the image?

Comment: If you cannot add any span or div to the text of the link there is no simple solution. You can use position absolute, or you can use a js simple code that analyze every a and invert img with text. Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Monteduro/nt44h5r5/16/